# How to eliminate username from authentication

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to eliminate the concept of a username from the django auth in my app. I want the `email` of the user to take place of the `username`. So I extended `AbstractBaseUser` with the code below

```
class AuthUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email address")

        user = self.model(email=self.normalize_email(email),)
        user.is_active = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email=email, password=password)
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message = "Only alphanumeric characters are allowed")


    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address',unique=True, max_length=255)
    first_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric])
    last_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, validators=[alphanumeric])
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False)

    #custom fields
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telephone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    objects = AuthUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        fullname = self.first_name + self.last_name
        return fullname

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

In my serializers.py I have this

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = AuthUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

But when I try to register I get the following error:

```
{
    "username": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That kind of error message would come from a form. Are you using a registration form that still relies on `username`?

Comment: I'm using my app's REST API endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest-auth/registration/ to create the new user.

Answer (score 0):

In your serializer, you need to exclude `username` field, because you are  inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser` and you still have 'username' field, so add this `exclude = ('username',)`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AuthUser
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        exclude = ('username',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = AuthUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user
```

Comment: `username` field is not in `AuthUser`

Comment: @coldmind he is inheriting it from AbstractBaseUser.